# Ending and deleting a queue manager by force

Tags: ibm-mq

Currently I have a queue manager that no matter I do just fails to go away. I am trying to end it and delete it. This is in one of our development servers. Not sure what happened, our server went through host name changes. Currently when I do *dspmq*, I get:

```
QMNAME(QM_MIT)                                            STATUS(Status not available)
```

*endmqm* says:

```
AMQ8146: WebSphere MQ queue manager not available.
```

*dltmqm* says:

```
AMQ8041: The queue manager cannot be restarted or deleted because processes,
that were previously connected, are still running.
AMQ7018: The queue manager operation cannot be completed.
```

I googled and found that listener needs to be killed, which I did. I am running WebSphere MQ v7.1 on Linux.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `ps-ef | grep qmgrname` to find any remaining processes that were running as part of the QMgr or that were attached to the QMgr.

Next, do a `/opt/mqm/bin/amqiclen -x -F -m qmgrname` to get rid of any shared memory segments. The command will fail if you do not provide a fully-qualified path name and try to run it from your `$PATH` or a relative path.

See [WebSphere MQ utility amqiclen usage and description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21195096) for more details.

Comment: where can we find amqiclen in windows

Comment: The amqiclen utility is not provided for Windows. On the other hand, IBM has enhanced MQ so as to no longer require that utility. Their [current advice](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-should-i-not-run-ipcrm-nor-amqiclen) boils down to "if you think you need it, open a PMR and tell us why."